# Where can I find labelled data for handwritten Chinese characters?

Tags: data-request, text, china

I would like to write a simple project that can recognise different written Chinese characters. Now I have been searching various web pages and other sources for a sufficient database to use.

While there are several databases offering free data to use, most of the data is not labelled. The closest to a success I have come was from this web page: http://www.hcii-lab.net/data/onHCCTestdataset/onHCCTest.html

On this web page I found "labels" and "data", however the labels seemed to far outnumber the data. So I can't be sure, if the files are related.

It would already be enough for me, if I had a data points and a labels files I could process (somehow) - the processing aspect of the data shouldn't be the difficult part. It also does not have to be "much" data - I don't have to have enough data so that any and every Chinese characters can identified.

In fact my expectation for the project aren't high - it's intended to be just a project I do for fun over my summer holidays. It's more important to me, that I can try and utilise Machine Learning algorithm for a hobby (Chinese) and in the end have something that works.

Answer (score 3):

[This resource](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~qiao/database.html) has a link to a bunch of online and off line databases for handwritten letters.

[This offline database](http://www.is.aist.go.jp/etlcdb/#English) seems to be a big one, hosted in Japan by Electrotechnical Laboratory has 1.2 million samples from Chinese, Japanese and other languages.

Nakagawa Labs has another [online database](http://web.tuat.ac.jp/~nakagawa/database/index.html), but it's not openly available.